# Calling overridden methods if the base method is not virtual

Tags: c++, c++11

In general, overriding a virtual method makes it possible to use the overridden method as follows:

```
class base
{
  public:
  virtual void start() {std::cout << "base start" << std::endl;}
  virtual void stop() {std::cout << "base stop" << std::endl;}
  void doSomething() { start(); stop(); }
};

class derived : public base
{
  public:
   void start() {std::cout << "derived start" << std::endl;}
   void stop() {std::cout << "derived stop" << std::endl;}
};

int main () {
    derived d;
    d.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code snippet is:

```
derived start
derived stop
```

My question is, how can I achieve the same behavior if functions `start()` and `stop()` were not virtual in the base class?

**Additional Information:**

What I want probably violates the polymorphic concepts. Nonetheless, I am very curious to see if there is a solution, even a hack-y one.

Comment: `start`and `stop` are virtual because they are virtual in the base class. I'm not sure what you want, that's the definition of `virtual`. If you want the same without `virtual`, you need to implement manually a vtable. Which makes no sense. Also in C++11, you should use `override` on the override methods.

Comment: I assume the motivation behind this is to extend some class that you don't have control over?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need it since in a project I am working on, I need some method to be virtual. However, I don't have access to the base class to make it virtual.

Comment: @0x5453 Thank you very much. Yes, exactly.

Comment: If the class doesn't have `virtual`, there is a reason for that. The developer didn't design it to do so. If you need to do something similar, then design your own class, use the original one as an implementation detail, and inherit from your own original class.

Comment: Is it to be used in existing code that was using `Base`? Or your own code? For 1, there is no solution, for 2, see my previous comment.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, That you. Your point is very valid. Nonetheless, I am trying to see if there is a way around it. Redesigning the class will take more than couple months, if it was a work for a few days, I'd definitely do it.

Comment: Well, that's the only option that I know of. If you don't need to pass your inherited objet to existing code (because that's impossible).

Comment: Are you being handed objects from some factory that you don't have access to or are you creating these in your code? I take it the issue is that other code you can't get to is calling what you want to override. Or is it?

Comment: @lakeweb, yes the base function is being handed to me and I cannot modify it. In worst case I have to re-implement it (i.e., copy it). This is not a desired solution since I cannot get the updates in future.

Comment: Hi mmotamedi144, yes, i understand the code is unavailable. But what I'm asking is do you create the `objects`. Are calls to the objects methods done by code you don't have access to. Or, do you `Base your_object;`. And then solely use the object yourself.

Comment: You could write an adapter class of sorts. A templated class which takes a type T and defines (e.g. with ``std::function``), how the ``dosomething()`` function is implemented in a particular case.  Then for the (old) standard cases you just have it use the doSomething() function of the base classes and for new derived ones, you have it use another member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to be able to call those methods that you marked *virtual* in the base class via a function called "doSomething" (or whatever your actual application is), in the way that you demonstrated. Then you can also override "doSomething" in the derived class by copying its definition from the base class like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
  void start() {std::cout << "base start" << std::endl;}
  void stop() {std::cout << "base stop" << std::endl;}
  void doSomething() { start(); stop(); }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
  void start() {std::cout << "derived start" << std::endl;}
  void stop() {std::cout << "derived stop" << std::endl;}
  void doSomething() { start(); stop(); }
};

int main () {
    derived d;
    d.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm sure you realize that duplicating a method like this in a derived class smells. So it is better not to do so.

If you had intended to use *late binding* somewhere else in your code, then you will into problems if you avoid using *virtual*. For example, changing "main" to the following:

```
int main () {
    base* d = true ? new derived : new base;
    d->doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Will always call the base class's methods without *virtual*.